# EF6 inserting float values

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I want to store a percentage value in my database built with EF6.

so i defined:

```
[Column(TypeName = "float")]
[Range(0, 1)]
public float RepeatedPointValuePercentage { get; set; }
```

If I insert `0.12` to the database the value in the table is `0.11999999731791`

Code that inserts the value:

```
var o = new Object{ RepeatedPointValuePercentage = 12f / 100;}
//add to dbset & save changes
```

How can i fix it without a migration?

Comment: What do you want to fix exactly? The value 0.12  just cannot be represented exactly as a float, 0.11999999731791 is close enough. It is just that a float cannot exactly represent 0.12 I think

Answer (score 2):

You should **NEVER** use float for accuracy wise. As @helper answered, this is how the float value is stored (An approximate-number data-type) and there is nothing you can do to fix it.

However, you can use `DECIMAL` instead which will handle this scenario.